# Autolayout UIImageView without image

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a UIImageView, with scaling Center, so it's size changes according to the UIImage inside, however, by setting a nil UIImage, the constraints break, as no content size can be calculated

**How to handle the autolayout with nil UIImage (the size should be changed to 0,0)?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that `UIImageView` returns {-1, -1} as intrinsicContentSize when no image is set. Use subclass of `UIImageView` with implementation like this:

```
@implementation MyImageView

- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if (self.image)
    {
        return [super intrinsicContentSize];
    }

    return CGSizeZero;
}

@end
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. One minor addition: You might also want to check if the image's size is zero, and in that case, also return `CGSizeZero`, as the default would be {-1, -1}.

Answer (score 13):

[@nikita-ivaniushchenko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26122574) gave me an idea to add `Width` constraint with `Low (250)` priority equals to `0` to `UIImageView`, so it is applied when `UIImage` is set to `nil`.

[image: Storyboard UIImage Constraints Example]

> Note: I added `Width` constraint only, because there was only issue with `UIImageView`'s width in my case. Should work for both, though.

Comment: Why should it work? I will try tonight but I'm curious what is behind the answer

Comment: I don't know for sure, however, what I suspect, the `intrinsicContentSize` is just some internal constraints, created automatically for our convenience. When we add our height/width constraint, the `intrinsicContentSize`'s constrains either removed or have a lower priority.

Comment: @yitschak it worth noting that I gained my assumption based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26353000/1492173)

Comment: It's working for me, just not with 250 but with 500 (or 750). No clue why.

Comment: It also works for me with width = 0, priority > 250. I guess `intrinsicContentSize` has the lowest priority and setting priority to 250 (lowest) let `intrinsicContentSize` to take over. So setting priority anything > 250 just helps. Thanks for this great tip, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Set `Content hugging priority` to `Required` (1000).

**Update**: This answer was working before, but it doesn't work now. *Use Nikita Ivaniushchenko* answer instead.

Comment: just checked once again on iOS 8. When `UIImageView` has `nil` image set, it won't change its size to {0,0}. Consider you have something like this: `|-[imageView]-[label]-|` when there is no image set, the `UIImageView` size will be expanded to maximum available space, no matter what value you set for `Content hugging priority`. It's because when there is no image set in `UIImageView` its `intrinsicContentSize` is {-1,-1} by default. @Nikita Ivaniushchenko answer is a proper solution.

Comment: @Darrarski I created test project and I should say that you're right — at this moment it doesn't work. I have no idea why Apple changed that behaviour recently.