# How to increase tabbar height in ios

Tags: ios, tabbar

How to increase the tab bar height in iOS,i tried many ways,none worked to me.My complete tab bar code is in app delegate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing the height of UITabBar in iOS7/8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397189/changing-the-height-of-uitabbar-in-ios7-8)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a moment to read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). You're expected to have already done basic research, to present the code you've tried with a description of how it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    CGRect tabFrame = self.tabBar.frame; //self.TabBar is IBOutlet of your TabBar
    tabFrame.size.height = 80;
    tabFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - 80;
    self.tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
}
```

You have to add following code to your subclass of UITabBarController class.

Comment: instead of copy paste the answer, provide the the reference link from share button.

Comment: ya sujay ,,,ill follow hereafter

Answer (score -1):

I am using an extension for changing height of tab-bar

```
 class CustomHeightTabBar : UITabBar {
        @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 0.0

        override func sizeOfTab(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
            var sizeOfTab = super.sizeOfTab(size)
            if height > 0.0 {
                sizeOfTab.height = height
            }
            return sizeOfTab
        }
    }
```

find more from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54305906/9977451)