# Swift3 - UICollectionViewCel's intrinsicContentSize is (-1, -1)

Tags: ios, swift

When I try to get cell's `intrinsicContentSize` in function `collectionView(_:didSelectItemAt:)`, the result is (-1, -1).

I am using flow layout with auto layout config of cell's subviews and did not implement `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`. Does anyone have ideas?

**Edit:**

the auto layout of cell has fixed width and height. I turned on self-sizing by setting `estimatedItemSize` and config the collectionView as following:

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? 
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
}
```

And I try to get the cell's `intrinsicContentSize` in:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    let size = cell?.intrinsicContentSize
}
```

which gives me `(-1, -1)` for `size`

Comment: put more code you have implemented

Comment: Check out answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127032/proper-usage-of-intrinsiccontentsize-and-sizethatfits-on-uiview-subclass-with-a

Answer (score 1):

A UICollectionViewCell has no `intrinsicContentSize`. Why do you expect it to have one?

- If you want to know what size the cell is at this moment, just ask for its `bounds.size`.
- If you want to know what size the cell would take on if it were sized from inside by the autolayout constraints of its subviews, call `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`.

Comment: Yes, I realised this after that. Actually I would like to implement an expandable and collapsable cell which contains labels when tapping, and just thought `intrinsicContentSize` can reveal the size that fits all labels with full content shown

Comment: Sounds to me like what you want is `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`. Added that to my answer.

Comment: Just realize you are the author of the book "iOS 10 programming" and I am studying on it~ So nice to meet you LOL @matt

Comment: Great but I don't seem to be helping you with _this_ question :(

Comment: Yes you have helped me realize that `intrinsicContentSize` is designed for views like `UILabel` and given me the useful method `systemLayoutSizeFitting(_:)`. I realize I need to read more on Apple's programming guides. In before I thought they are a little bit verbose haha